# Autofac generic decorator is duplicating components

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, decorator, autofac

I have found what I think may be a bug in Autofac, but I wanted to see if anybody had a possible solution or workaround so I can make this work.

Basically I have set up a generic decorator, which works fine. The problem is that as soon as I call `BeginLifetimeScope()` with a configuration delegate, it erroneously resolves multiple components of the same type. If I don't use a configuration delegate with `BeginLifetimeScope()`, then it works correctly. Unfortunately, I need to add additional dependencies to my child scope, so not using a configuration delegate is not an option.

Here is an example that demostrates the problem:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Dependency>()
    .Named<IDependency<object>>("service");
builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
    typeof(Decorator<>), typeof(IDependency<>), "service", "decorated");
var container = builder.Build();

// Returns 1
var scope1 = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
Console.WriteLine(
    scope1.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IDependency<object>>>("decorated").Count());

// Returns 2 - notice the configAction doesn't even have to do anything
var scope2 = container.BeginLifetimeScope(r => { });
Console.WriteLine(
    scope2.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IDependency<object>>>("decorated").Count());
```

And here are my fake types:

```
interface IDependency<T> { }

class Dependency : IDependency<object> { }

class Decorator<T> : IDependency<T> {}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does just seem like a bug. As a workaround, I ended up doing the following:

```
var param = new TypedParameter(typeof(IDecoratorDependency), new DecoratorDependency());
var decorated = scope.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IDependency<object>>>("decorated", param);
```

That was good enough for my use case. However, this method is inflexible because it only allows me to supply parameters  to the root object, in this case `Decorator<T>`, but not any of its dependencies.